# popup dialog- iOS

Tags: ios, popup

What is the best way to implement a popup dialogue for iOS?

I need a UIView that allows the user to select smileys, and a button to dismiss the UIView

I do not know enough about Apple's interface guidelines to make the decision. Are there any apple classes that I should use, or 3rd party open source projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a small custom dialog box, where users can select arbitrary items, just add a **UIView** to your **view controller**, with a frame thats smaller than the whole window. Then just hide and show it by changing the `hidden` property

Comment: There are a good number of existing questions here on that provide answers to your question. A search for iOS popup (and possibly adding "ipad" or "iphone" depending on your target device) will likely turn up some useful suggestions.